# Could you please help me find another example of motion under null net force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

There are many familiar situations in which the net force on a body is zero and yet the body 
moves with a constant velocity.

Here is one example:

> A car traveling at constant speed on a straight road has the force of the 
>   road on the tires just balanced by the force of air friction.  If the gas pedal is depressed further, the tires will push against the road harder and the road 
>   will push against the tires harder; so the car will accelerate forward – until 
>   the air friction builds up enough to balance the greater drive force.

Could YOU please help me find another example of a body moving with constant velocity under balanced forces? Please specify the cause of each force on the body and explain how these forces could be changed to affects the body’ motion.

Comment: all examples of motion at constant velocity are good examples. this is Newton's law. if the net force is zero, so is the acceleration. hence constant velocity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any body which is free falling in a viscous medium will reach a terminal velocity. Although mathematically this is usually attained after an infinite amount of time, from a physical point of view you can assume that such velocity, up to uncertainties, is actually reached by the body after a finite transient. The forces that come into play are the fluid viscosity and the gravitational pull, although in some cases buoyancy might be a relevant force too.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful, but I need a real world  example of that please!

Comment: like someone jumping from a plane and opening up their parachute to safely reach the ground?